# How to uniform the reading data from the gyroscope sensor from different devices?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, gyroscope, qgyroscopereading

I'm developing an app based on AR and orientation of the device, the problem is that different devices give me different data from the gyroscope. Probably because the different hardware, but at this point there is a system to uniforming the results?

I also have the problem of working on Unity and not on Android Studio or Xcode, so the methods I can use are limited.

I'm using the `Input.gyro.attitude` to get the data and the results are not the same. Any suggestion?

```c#
Quaternion direction = Input.gyro.attitude;
```

Comment: I know nothing about the gyroscope but I would suspect that the initial `Input.gyro.attitude` depends on how the device is oriented when you first launch the app. Maybe you should combine it using GPS so both devices get the same initial oriantation?

Comment: No, I've already tested this case, and the Input.gyro.attitude is correct also in different orientations at the start.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by it gives different data? Is one facing the complete opposite direction of the other?

Comment: No, the devices I use (Huawei P20 and HTC Nexus 9) have a 30º degrees of difference approximately on orientation. They are not opposed.